# How to check the presence of a line in a string?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

how to find a specific string in a variable environment %path% from the batch file ?
I try so but it does not work

```
echo ;%PATH%; | find /C /I ";*ffmpeg*;"
```

and

```
ECHO %PATH% | findstr /n /r "*ffpmeg*"
```

why?

в powershell это намного проще сделать)

Comment: Super User is an English-only site, and all the questions and answers must be in English. Please [edit] your question and use English only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I try so but it does not work

> ```
> echo ;%PATH%; | find /C /I ";*ffmpeg*;"
> ```

`Find` does not support wildcards.

> Limitations
>
> ```
> `Find` does not support wildcards, use `FINDSTR` instead.
> ```

[Find - Search for text - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)

> ```
> ECHO %PATH% | findstr /n /r "*ffpmeg*"
> ```

1. You have misspelled `ffmpeg`
2. `findstr` does not support multiple `*` wildcards in the way that you are using them. Try the following:

   ```
   ECHO %PATH% | findstr /n /r ".*ffmpeg.*"
   ```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [find](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) - Search for a text string in a file & display all the lines where it is found.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.